# Next-Intl how to automatically set the current locale as a header to outbound api requests

Tags: next.js, middleware, app-router, next-intl

We are using the nextjs app router, along with [next-intl server components](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-server-components). We would have an external api and would like to send the current locale to the api with every api request. We are thinking we should be able to do this in the middleware quite easily as opposed to everywhere we construct a request, but are left wondering how we can get the "current locale" to send inside the middleware. Is the best strategy to check for a cookie?

Comment: Can't you just use the pathname inside the middleware? 
something like this:
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const locale = req.nextUrl.pathname.split("/")?.[0]
  // use this locale for your apis